# Does the ACTION_SEND Intent have an EXTRA to specify recipient's name?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using this `Intent` to open the email client:

```java
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"someLongAndUglyEmailAddress@example.com"})
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
```

Is there an `EXTRA` to specify the recipient's actual name? Or is that implemented solely by the email client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no extra for that from the doc https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email

That's the maximum that you can do to compose a new email

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```